# Redux - How to access a non-serializable object which is derived asynchronously?

Tags: canvas, reactjs, redux, react-redux

My user supplies a URL, and I want to use that URL as the background for a `<canvas>` element in my React+Redux app.This means the `render()` method of my React component needs access to an `<img>` DOM node containing the user’s image. Unfortunately setting the `src` attribute of an image tag is asynchronous, since the requested image will not actually populate in the DOM until the data has been fetched from the server.

Normally with an asynchronous task, like an API call for example, one would store the result of the asynchronous task directly into the Redux store, but from reading the [Redux docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-non-serializable), it appears storing non-serializable objects (like a DOM node) in the store is not advised.

Is there some other reasonable way to solve this problem? Currently I am abusing my React component's life-cycle methods to watch for the URL prop to change, and then setting the `<img>` DOM node into the component's state asynchronously, which feels very awkward.

Comment: So the user enters an URL and you want to store the BLOB? How are you setting the background?

Comment: @martriay I want to draw the image that the user supplies into the canvas. Using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the blob". For added clarity, I want to have the `<img>` node available to me long term so that I can redraw the `<canvas>` as the props change, always using the user's URL as the background.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you store the image URL in the store/state and you pass it to the [`Image` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image)?

Assuming you have the `url` in the `state`:

```js
render() {
  var bg = new Image()
  bg.src = this.state.url
  // here you use the bg as an <img> element
}
```

This way you don't set it as a callback but as a reaction to the state change instead.

Comment: Unfortunately you can't reliably make use of `bg` until it's "load" event has fired. If you try to use it right away, it will still be empty since the image has not been downloaded yet. See this answer for more context: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16006223/1263117

Comment: You're right. I think there is no other choice but to store the DOM element in the store and wait for the image to load by observing an `isReady` variable or something like it.